# Click event firing but .fadeIn not working

Tags: jquery

I can't see why the last click event isn't working. It should .fadeIn all list items and then .hide any list items that aren't matched. The .fadeIn doesn't seem to fire.

**Expected Behaviour**

- Filter by 'All, Rum & Cola'
- Secondary Filter by 'Blonde, Brunette'

http://jsfiddle.net/establish/V8c8C/

Any comments or improvements appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="drinks">
  <li data-drink="all"><a data-drink="all" href="#">All</a></li>
  <li data-drink="rum"><a data-drink="rum" href="#">Rum</a></li>
  <li data-drink="cola"><a data-drink="cola" href="#">Cola</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="drink-orders">
   <li class="blonde"><a class="blonde" data-drink="rum" href="#">Blonde</a></li>
   <li class="brunette"><a class="brunette" data-drink="cola" href="#">Brunette</a></li>
   <li class="blonde"><a class="blonde" data-drink="rum" href="#">Blonde</a></li>
   <li class="brunette"><a class="brunette" data-drink="cola" href="#">Brunette</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#drinks a').click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

var alcohol = $(this).attr("data-drink");

if ($(this).attr("data-drink") === "all") {
    $("#drink-orders li").fadeIn();
}

else {
    $("#drink-orders li").fadeIn();
    $("#drink-orders li:not([data-drink="+alcohol+"])").hide();  
}
});

$('#girls a').click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

var hair = $(this).attr("class");

$("#drink-orders li").fadeIn();
$("#drink-orders li:not(class="+hair+")").hide();

});
```

Comment: `fadeIn` only fades in if the element is not currently visible, otherwise it stays visible. Is this the problem?

Comment: There isn't a fadeIn on the second click event.  All you're doing is setting a variable called `hair`

Comment: Jsfiddle was playing up. Should be showing correct code now

Comment: @Dan, post your code here, not only on jsFiddle. This way, your question will not be affected by that site's mood swings.

Comment: FTR jsFiddle is lagging for many weeks - it simply became too popular and can't stand the volume of requests.

Comment: Hmm.. you can contact the developer of jsFiddle directly [in here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50024/152859) by posting comment on his answer.

Comment: OK cool. I've posted the code here now as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/V8c8C/9/

```
$('#drinks a').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var alcohol = $(this).attr("data-drink");

    if ($(this).attr("data-drink") === "all") {
        $("#drink-orders li").fadeIn();
    }

    else {
        $("#drink-orders li").fadeIn();
        $("#drink-orders li:not([data-drink="+alcohol+"])").hide();  
    }
});

$('#girls a').click(function(e) {

    var hair = $(this).attr("class");

    e.preventDefault();

    $("#drink-orders li:not(."+hair+")").hide();
    $("#drink-orders li."+hair).fadeIn();

});
```

Comment: The demo doesn't seem to work as intended? 'Blonde'and 'Brunette' don't filter down.

Comment: In the code i copied from here, the girls list didn't have data-drink defined, therefore the second click definition always shows all. It seems to have been updated since i copied it.

Comment: Yeah sorry, jsFiddle was playing up earlier and not saving code correctly. Your example now works as expected. Thanks!